# How to add button function instead of marker in google map?

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I want to link buttons with the marker info, if I press a button it
should popup info of particular marker. I want to link by using the 
`id` I have given the `id` but I am unable to understand how to write the function to link up marker info with the button please help me out of this. Thanks in advance. If any other simple solution to do this will be helpful for me.

Code:

```js
var locations = [
  [tendowningstreet.info, tendowningstreet.lat,
    tendowningstreet.long, 0
  ],
  [republicofnoodles.info, republicofnoodles.lat,
    republicofnoodles.long, 1
  ],
  [prego.info, prego.lat, prego.long, 2],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.447412, 78.376230), //Hitech 
  city Address
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

var marker, i;


for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],
      locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));


  function click("button") {
    var button.id = [marker.i]; //The function is wrong i need help at this point.



  }

}
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><button type="button" id="1">10 Downing Street in 
              Gachibowli</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" id="2">Republic of Noodles in 
              Madhapur</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" id="3">Prego in Madhapur</button>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="map"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `data-attributes` and keeping a map of locations and markers with same keys. Here is a rough idea of the same. There is a lot to explain in a single answer, you can ask any questions in the comments.

```js
// Stub
var google = {
  maps: {
    InfoWindow: function InfoWindow(){
       this.content = null;
       this.setContent = function(content) {this.content = content};
       this.open = function() {console.log(arguments, this.content)};
    },
    Marker: function Marker(){this.name = "Marker"},
    Map: function Map(){this.name = "Map"},
    LatLng: function LatLng(){},
    event: {addListener : function(){}}
  }
};

var locations = getLocations();
var map = createMap('map');
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
var markers = createMarkersForLocations(locations, infowindow);
bindButtonEvents(map, infowindow, markers, locations);


function createMarkersForLocations(locations, infowindow) {
  var markerMap = {};
  for (key in locations) {
    if (locations.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      markerMap[key] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[key].lat,
          locations[key].long),
        map: map
      });

      markerMap[key].originalLocation = locations[key];

      google.maps.event.addListener(markerMap[key], 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.originalLocation.info);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }
  }
  return markerMap;
}


function createMap(id) {
  return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.447412, 78.376230)
  });
}

/**
 * <button type="button" data-key="republicOfNoodles">Republic of Noodles in Madhapur</button>
 */
function bindButtonEvents(map, infowindow, markers, locations) {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button')).forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var key = this.getAttribute('data-key');
        infowindow.setContent(locations[key].info);
        infowindow.open(map, markers[key]);
      })
    });
}

function getLocations() {
  return {
    tenDowningStreet: { info: 'Tending Down Street', lat: 17.447412, long: 78.376230 },
    republicOfNoodles: { info: 'Republic of noodles', lat: 17.447412, long: 78.376230 },
    prego: { info: 'Prego', lat: 17.447412, long: 78.376230 }
  }
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><button type="button" data-key="tenDowningStreet">10 Downing Street in 
              Gachibowli</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" data-key="republicOfNoodles">Republic of Noodles in 
              Madhapur</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" data-key="prego">Prego in Madhapur</button>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer it helped me.